# Disable past dates in <p:calendar>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

How to disable past dates in a `<p:calendar>`?

```
<p:calendar value="#{userData.datein}" />
```

Comment: Any day before today is considered a past day. As such, what exactly do you mean by "*Past dates*". Do you really want to disable any date before today's date?

Comment: Yeah i dont want user to select any date before today's date.

Comment: In other words, you want to set a minimum date? Did you check the (tag) documentation if there is an attribute available for that?

Comment: Yeah I have seen about the minimum date, but how to set the property to current date value?

Comment: The same way as you would set the value of the calendar to the current date. Or any input field.

Comment: Huh? If you have already seen it, why didn't you tell about that and/or explicitly ask to [java] users how to set a Java `Date` variable to the current date..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used like this  and its working fine

```
<p:calendar id="datein" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="#{userData.datein}" mindate="today"/>
```

Javascript code

```
<script>
today = Date();
</script>
```

Comment: user can type previous date. how to restrict him from writing previous date.

Comment: `mindate` cannot be a JavaScript variable! See https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/calendar

Answer (score 5):

You can do like this.

XHTML-

```
<p:calendar value="#{viewBean.dateSelected}" mindate="#{viewBean.todayDate}" />
```

ViewBean-

```
private Date todayDate = new Date();

public Date getTodayDate() {
    return todayDate;
}
```

Comment: user can type previous date. how to restrict him from writing previous date.

Comment: I believe in that case it must not allow to enter date before mindate or throw error message on form submission, but right now i am not sure about that. Have you yried that? If it won't work you can write a custom validator which will do it for you.